# Value for XML Root Element is completely wrong, not finding child nodes

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a very basic XML file that looks like this:

```
<allData>
  <allDataDetails>
    <quoteid>ABC123</quoteid>
    <customername>John Smith</customername>
  </allDataDetails>
  <allDataDetails>
    <quoteid>DEF456</quoteid>
    <customername>Jane Doe</customername>
  </allDataDetails>
</allData>
```

My XSD specifies that at least 1 allDataDetails element must exist. The doc is validated fine.

When querying using Linq to XML, though, I cannot seem to recognize or query for the inner elements within allData. Instead, when I view in the debugger, the Value attribute is all the data concatenated. It looks like this:

```
ABC123John SmithDEF456Jane Doe
```

Here's my query code. myRows is always null, because I cannot seem to get the descendants:

```
XDocument entityXml = XDocument.Parse(myDataString);

var myRows = from d in entityXml.Descendants("allDataDetails")
             select new
             {
                quoteid = d.Element("quoteid").Value,
                customername = d.Element("customername").Value
             };
```

Anyone know what could be wrong here?

Comment: Very odd that your XSD validated this - the `<quoteid>` tags are not properly closed..... the closing tags as `</quote>` which don't match the opening tag.....

Comment: But when the XML is fixed up, and the missing comma between the two assignment in the `select new {}` is fixed, too - the result seems to be OK. The two nodes are properly selected and the proper data is extracted - what exactly is your problem in the end?!?!?!?!

Comment: the typos were left by the last person to edit my original entry.

Comment: they were in your original post, too ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just run your sample code, and few syntax error were fixed:
 and also a comma for the value customer name was wrong, try my version below, it should work.

```
string myDataString = @"<allData>
                          <allDataDetails>
                            <quoteid>ABC123</quoteid>
                            <customername>John Smith</customername>

                          </allDataDetails>
                          <allDataDetails>
                            <quoteid>DEF456</quoteid>
                            <customername>Jane Doe</customername>

                          </allDataDetails>
                        </allData>";
             XDocument entityXml = XDocument.Parse(myDataString);


             var myRows = from d in entityXml.Descendants("allDataDetails")
                      select new
                        {
                            quoteid = d.Element("quoteid").Value
                            ,customername = d.Element("customername").Value
                        };
             foreach (var rw in myRows)
                 Console.WriteLine(rw.customername + "\t" + rw.quoteid);
```

Comment: I am still having issues. On my end, when I view the properties for entityXml in the debugger, they are always wrong. I am loading the file into an XmlDocument object and passing in the OuterXml value as a string to the method thats acting up. Here's a screenshot of my locals window. http://screencast.com/t/nbkYm6gA - youll see that for some reason the Root is the entire string, and all the values have been concatenated.

Comment: I have exactly the same results as marc_s and have no problem in the code. Marc_S is correct, you should look at myRows variable.

Comment: You have a stray comma there after `d.Element("customername").Value`.

Answer (score 2):

I have the impression you're looking **at the wrong variable** in your locals window - you're looking at the entire XDocument, and it's `.Value` property will indeed be something like a concatenated string of all node values.....

But you **really should look** at the `MyRows` variable - and if you're really executing the code you posted, you should see this:

[image] ([full picture here](http://i41.tinypic.com/dr8gux.png))

Isnt' that what you're looking for / expecting???